# The missing script:"dev" error in react on npm run dev

Tags: reactjs

this is my package.json file it's a code from a course to test my code functionality.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebn1n.png)

The npm run build is working by the way & I'm using vite to run the npm.

```json
{
  "name": "adopt-me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev":"vite",
    "build":"vite build",
    "preview":"vite preview",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo\"Error: no test specified\"&& exit1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "vite": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

to run my react on browser in, I expecting to get a localhost number to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot:

You need to run `npm run dev` not `npm run div`

Comment: it worked  and it's giving me a local host(http://127.0.0.1:5173/) but it's tell me This site can’t be reached

Comment: oh never mind I tried it again it's working now 
thank you :)

Comment: Thanks you can mark as the answer if this helped solve your issue.

Comment: I'm trying to give your answer a up arrow but it's telling me this  (You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.) and i just made my stack overflow account